# Angular: subscribe does nothing when recalling function

Tags: javascript, angular, subscribe

I have a component where I use route parameters to switch "tabs". I'm subscribed to the route parameters, so whenever I switch between the tabs I recall the function for that tab. One of the functions is this one:

```
getUserFeed() {
console.log('testUser');
this.currentTab = "2";
this.loading = true;

this.authService.userData$.subscribe(data => {
  this.user = data;

  this.userAsteroid$ = this.userAsteroidService.getAsteroids();
  this.userAsteroid$.subscribe(asteroids => {
    this.asteroidIds = [];

    asteroids.forEach(document => {
      if (document.userId == this.user.uid) {
        this.asteroidIds.push(document.asteroidId);
      }
    });

    this.asteroidIds.forEach(asteroidObservable => {
      console.log("test:", asteroidObservable);
      var data$;
      data$ = this.neoService.getLookup$(asteroidObservable);

      data$.subscribe(asteroid => {
        this.dataArray.push(asteroid);
      });
    });

    this.loading = false;
    console.log("data & asteroids", this.dataArray, this.asteroidIds);
  });
});
```

This function works fine the first time I call it, but when I call it a second time, everything in the subscription `this.authService.userData$.subscribe(data => {}` just doesn't happen. Not even a console log with a string does anything.

Also, when I reload the page in the browser, everything in `this.authService.userData$.subscribe(data => {}` happens twice.

Anyone know what causes this?

*EDIT*

I originally said the function doesn't work when called as second time from the same component, but I realized it doesn't work a second time called from anywhere in the site. In order for it to work I have to reload my website.

I'm using the firebase authentication system. My auth service:

```
userData$: BehaviorSubject<User> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {
  this.afAuth.authState.subscribe((user) => {
     this.setUserData(user);
  });
 }

private setUserData(user) {
if (user !== null) {
  this.userData$.next({
    uid: user.uid,
    displayName: user.displayName || user.email,
    photoURL: user.photoURL || '/assets/icons/icon-72x72.png',
    email: user.email,
  });
} else {
  this.userData$.next(null);
}
```

Comment: It's probably a `share()` observable, can you show how the `authService.userData$` is created?

Comment: how do you call this function?

Comment: @PierreDuc I added it to the question

Comment: @Mac_W Inside ngOnInit, I have a subscribe for my route parameters, like this: "this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {}". Inside that I have a switch on the tab parameter, where I call a function for each tab, this being one of them.

Comment: @WimNaudts we need to fully see how you subscribe to the route params as well

Comment: You subscription will be triggered only when you call `userData$.next`. If it's triggered twice on load, then it means you have called it twice. If it doesn't get triggered when you change tabs, it means you haven't called it. We will need a [mcve] to tell you exactly what is wrong, but knowing what I just explained, you should be able to find the issue by yourself.

Comment: The best way to trace the calls is to call `console.trace` in your `setUserData` function, so that you see from where it is called.

Comment: @trichetriche I now realize it actually doesn't work a second time from anywhere in my webapp. In order for it to work, I have to reload the page.

Comment: @WimNaudts or as said, you must call `userData$.next`

Comment: @WimNaudts - your auth service gets called only once when it is initialized when the app loads. The service calls this.setUserData(user) only once and this is the service which returns a new subscription using next.

Comment: I changed it so that now the userfeed function only gets called in the ngOnInit() once, and after subscribing to the userData$, instead of inside it. Now I can switch between tabs and it works, but now when I go to another component and then go back, it won't get inside this.userAsteroid$.subscribe(asteroids => {} anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it thanks to the commenters.

First off, to avoid getting the data 2 times I had to put the bulk of my code outside of the userData$ subscribe. Then I had to put my getUserFeed() in the ngOnInit(), so that it doesn't get called everytime I change tabs. I also have to unsubscribe from the userAsteroid$ for when I revisit the page and call the function again.

It now looks like this

```
ngOnInit() {
this.authService.userData$.subscribe(data => {
  this.user = data;
});
this.getUserFeed();}

this.getUserFeed(){
   this.userAsteroid$ = this.userAsteroidService.getAsteroids();
   this.astroSub = this.userAsteroid$.subscribe(asteroids => {
   this.asteroidIds = [];

   asteroids.forEach(document => {
      if (document.userId == this.user.uid) {
         this.asteroidIds.push(document.asteroidId);
      }
   });

   this.asteroidIds.forEach(asteroidObservable => {
      console.log("test:", asteroidObservable);
      var data$;
      data$ = this.neoService.getLookup$(asteroidObservable);

      data$.subscribe(asteroid => {
        this.dataUserArray.push(asteroid);
      });
   });

   this.loading = false;

   this.astroSub.unsubscribe();
   console.log("data & asteroids", this.dataUserArray, this.asteroidIds);
});}
```